# Get all values from LinkedHashMap where key = x

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I have a LinkedHashMap. How can I get all the values where the key is equal to what the user select?

Comment: the key is unique. so what you mean with all values?

Comment: There will only be one value per key... `map.get(x)` ?

Comment: Please see the posting guidelines for Stack Overflow and include some code in your post, thanks!

Comment: How do you get value from a map? `yourMap.get(yourKey);`

Comment: I would have to guess that you have a LinkedHashMap<Object, List<Object>> or something of the like...  please update your question with more information so we might help you.

Comment: I mean that I have several values in my hash, which happen to have the same key. Why give minus if you don't understand the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value of a 'Key' you just need to iterate through the entry set. Not sure if this is what you want - but as comments suggest you're quite vague with what you actually want.  Post some code for a better answer!

```
 Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();

    map.put("one", "value 1");
    map.put("two", "value 2");
    map.put("three", "value 3");

    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()){

      if (entry.getKey().equals("two")){

        System.out.println(entry.getValue());

      }

    }
```